# Vim syntax highlighting problems with Haskell

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Normally vim is very good with syntax highlighting, it hasn't given me any problems with HTML, Javascript, Python, etc., but now I'm using Haskell and it doesn't want to cooperate. Here's what it looks like : [Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HfWF.png)
Here's what the tutorial I'm following looks like : [His](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAYyT.png)
I've tried running vim without my .vimrc, and then it's just all white, no syntax coloring at all. I've tried disabling all my plugins, and then it's the same as in the first picture. How can I get it to highlight syntax like in the second picture?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like syntax highlighting is just fine, only does your *colorscheme* hide some syntax elements by defining identical colors, whereas the other has distinct colors.

Try out different colorschemes, or dive into the details of your colorscheme and the Haskell syntax, and change some links, e.g.:

```
hi link hsInfix Statement
```

For this, you need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the used syntax group, you can relink it to one of the basic groups that the colorscheme defines.

Also, read `:help ft-haskell-syntax`; the syntax plugin has some customizations built-in.